# Frogs stop croaking at same time

Tags: ethology, sociality, animal-psychology

I know frogs start croaking at the same time to attract a female.

Why do they all stop at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling is a risky activity because it makes the frog conspicuous to predators. When calling in a group, the risk to any given individual is minimized to the point that the minimal risk is outweighed by the advantage of attracting a mate. However, a single frog calling on his own is assuming all of the predation risk. So, the frogs are playing a bit of game theory and when too few are calling simultaneously to make the risk worthwhile, they will all tend to stop.